# Beautiful Soup: Replace a part of an image's source that was returned

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm new to python and new to beautiful soup, so to practice I made an image scraper that works for the most part.  I am able to find the images and download them to my computer and put them into folders based on their name.  But I've ran into an issue.  This is my code

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import os.path

url = "https://example.net/g/1"
i = 1
data = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(data.text, 'html.parser')
for sou in soup.findAll("div", {"class": "gallery"}):
    sou.decompose()

containers = soup.find_all('img')
title = soup.find('h1').text
imgsrc = containers

for imgs in imgsrc: 
    if ".jpg" in imgs['src']:
        sauce = (imgs['src'])

        if sauce[:1] =="/":
          image = 'https:' + sauce
        else:
          image = sauce

        nametemp = imgs.get('alt')
        if nametemp is None:
                filename = str(i)
                i = i+1
                print(image)
```

and when I run this, I get these image sources back,

1. https://t.example.net/galleries/9/cover.jpg
2. https://t.example.net/galleries/9/1t.jpg
3. https://t.example.net/galleries/9/2t.jpg

This is what I want for the most part, but the sources that are returned are thumbnails so they are small.  To get to the full sized images, its pretty easy.  Just replace the two Ts.

My question is how can I replace the above with this

1. https://i.example.net/galleries/9/1.jpg
2. https://i.example.net/galleries/9/2.jpg

I tried using replace_with() and I've looked at the documentation, but i'm having a bit of understanding it.

Comment: in ordinary situation the full size image is contained in it. Try to find it, if you insist your idea you can try this  `newurl = url[:8]+"i"+url[9:-5]+".jpg" if url.find("t.jpg") > 0 else url[:7]+"i"+url[9:]`

Answer (score 0):

Your code is quite messy and not relevant to your question. So let's assume you have a list of URLs called `thumbnails`:

```
thumbnails = [
    'https://t.example.net/galleries/9/1t.jpg',
    'https://t.example.net/galleries/9/2t.jpg',
    'https://t.example.net/galleries/9/3t.jpg',
]
```

You could then use a regex replace inside a list comprehension to convert the URLs like you wanted:

```
import re
images = [re.sub(r't(\.jpg)', r'\1', url) for url in thumbnails]
```

Comment: I put my code because I'm not sure if it would be relevant.  I'm not sure how to word this,, but is there a way to convert the contents of image into a list of url's like you did, change the t and remove the t, and re run it through beautifulsoup?

Comment: You can edit your own question and remove all the unnecessary comments and new lines. If the code works by simple copy-and-paste I might reread it.